# Openmp threading with for each

Tags: c++, openmp

I have started working with OpenMP. It worked for me with a regular for loop (ex: `for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)`). However, I haven't been able to get it to work with a for each loop. I read a post on StackOverflow that addresses the question (i think), but, I don't understand how to implement it. How do I do it?

Comment: What is _"for each loop"_?

Comment: Please add  a [mcve] of what you want to parallelize and what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you are just starting to add parallelism to a C++ code (and have no external requirement to use OpenMP), you may find other options more C++ friendly (e.g. the C++ 17 Parallel STL, or Threading Building Blocks (TBB) https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question fully. 
Never less, to my knowledge OpenMP can only handle `for' loops.

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
{
  // do something here
}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers and happy coding.

Comment: So I can't use it for a for each loop? (for(int x: array))

Comment: Just for clarification - regarding the "for each loop", are you using C++11 or higher version of C++ standard?